# Electronic speed controllers and total current draw

Tags: esc, current

Do we have to take Electronic Speed Controllers (ESC) into account when calculating the total current draw of the system?

As far as I can understand, the motor and ESC are connected in series, so we take the component that draws the most current, which is the motor in this case. Then, all combinations of a motor and ESC are connected in parallel, thus the currents add up. Am I thinking right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What are you trying to estimate using the total current draw?

Comment: I'm trying to estimate two things: what kind of battery I need in terms of C and mAh, and what the total flight time will be (although it will not be very accurate since there are other factors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. There will be a small amount of current used for the ESC electronics that are not in series with the motor, but that should be negligible.